# ImportError while importing node module

Tags: javascript, node.js, npm, yolo

I have created a local server that serves a single HTML file with node. I have two diffrent folders, one having the server and node_modules files and .json files, the other one having static files (HTML and predict.js). How can I import a module from npm to the static index.js ?

```
//In predict.js I have
import yolo from 'tfjs-yolo';
```

I got the error `Uncaught TypeError: Failed to resolve module specifier "tfjs-yolo". Relative references must start with either "/", "./", or "../".`

I have specified that predict.js is a module in the HTML file.

```
<script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.3.1.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/@tensorflow/tfjs@0.11.7"></script>
<script src="imagenet_classes.js"></script>
<script type="module" src="predict.js"></script>
```

I have one other question, I have seen that CDN Deliver can be used to import npm modules directly. when I add the script `<script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/tfjs-yolo@0.0.4/dist/index.bundle.min.js"></script>` in the HTML file and I try to call yolo variable in predict.js, I got an error stating that yolo is not defined.

Thank you.